# How can I make create a tibble with a column that is of type vector?

Tags: r, vector, tibble

Say I have tibble that looks like this

```
tib1 < tibble(x = 1:5, y = 0)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y: num  0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I get column y to look like this:

```
$ x: int 1 2 3 4 5
$ y: vector c(1,0,0,0,0) c(0,1,0,0,0) c(0,0,1,0,0) ...
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your desired `y` column is most certainly not type `vector`, that's a `list`. What you want is a *list-column*. (It happens to be that the elements of that `list` are vectors, but that's no requirement.) How about `tib1$y <- list(c(1,0,0,0,0), c(0,1,0,0,0), ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tabulate` and create a `list` column based on the value of 'x'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
tib1 %>% 
     mutate(y = map(x, ~ tabulate(.x,  max(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
library(tibble)
n <- 5
tib1 <- tibble(x = 1:n, y = split(diag(n), rep(1:n, n)))
```

will give

```
> tib1$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> tib1$y
$`1`
[1] 1 0 0 0 0

$`2`
[1] 0 1 0 0 0

$`3`
[1] 0 0 1 0 0

$`4`
[1] 0 0 0 1 0

$`5`
[1] 0 0 0 0 1
```